# Slow performance of WMS server

Tags: wms, web-mapping, web-service, qgis-server

I have QGIS Map Server, when I load WMS layer it takes 20 seconds to prepare it and only 30ms to download. How can I speed it up?

Can I do this without changing QGIS projects? How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: What is your data source (PostGIS, Shapefile...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to profile your data sources and workspace as a whole.

With QGIS Server, you usually prepare the workspace in QGIS. How long does a similar map frame take to render in the Desktop application? Try with different layers and styling options in QGIS, and then publish to your server.

Some ideas:

- If you're rendering complex features, use a simplified version when you're zoomed out (use visibility based on scale to switch)
- For any layers in a spatial database, ensure that you're using a spatial index
- As the previous poster suggested, look into adding overviews to rasters (see GDAL's [gdaladdo](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) command
- For layers where you're showing only some of the features, remove them from the source data (so if you're showing major roads, but the dataset also has minor roads, export just the major roads)
- Ensure that layers are saved in the projection that they are rendered in, so that the server doesn't need to reproject on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you must create pyramid layers of you rasters using Gdaladdo command.

Using pyramid layers externally or internally will help you to speedup your WMS performance.

You can visit [gdaladdo](http://geospatialearth.in/gdaltools.php#gdaladdo) for help.